# I am trying to search my java multidimensional array from bottom right to top left going in a vertical pattern? What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array

I am trying to search my java multidimensional array from bottom right to top left for a word going in a vertical pattern, but it is not finding the word. What am I doing wrong?

```
      public static String findBottomToTop(char[][] board, String word) {
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();

        if (letters.length <= board.length) {
            int lettersIndex = 0;

            for (int i = board.length-1; i > -1; i--) {

                for (int j = board[i].length-1; j > -1; j--) {
                    if (board[i][j] == letters[0]) {
                        lettersIndex++;

                        for (int k = 0; k < letters.length; k++) {
                            if (j > board[k].length && board[k][j] == letters[lettersIndex]) {
                                lettersIndex++;

                                if (lettersIndex == letters.length) {
                                    return "String " + word + " found in row=" + i + " col=" + j;
                                }
                            } else {
                                // breaks
                                lettersIndex = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }// found first
                }
            }
        }
        return "String " + word + " not found";
    }
```

Comment: `if (j > board[k].length && board[k][j] == letters[lettersIndex])` ... shouldn't there be an `i` in there somewhere?

Comment: Shouldn't `j` be _less than_ `board[k].length`, in line 14? Also, didn't you say you wanted to search vertically? `board[k][j]`, with `k` starting at 0, is not going to achieve that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch

```
   for (int i = board[0].length-1; i > -1; i--) {

       for (int j = board.length-1; j > -1; j--) {
```

You want to loop at the farthest right corner all the way up through the rows then move left and do same thing.  Just change the logic of your loops.